# how to delete object b, after setting object a to it, but not remove object a aswell?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do this:

```
   Data4JS D4JS = (Data4JS)GlobalHelper.GetCurrentSession()["Data4JS"];
    GlobalHelper.GetCurrentSession()["Data4JS"] = null; 
    return D4JS;
```

Problem is it sets D4JS to null as well, I don't really want to split my code up into a few method calls, how else can I acheive this easily?

Comment: You need to clone object. try to search about objects cloning/copying.

Comment: If `D4JS` is not null after the first line, there's no reason it should be null after the second line. Go and try it with any associative collection (`Dictionary` for example). Something else happens then and your snippet is missing these important details. My advice is that you debug this twice, figure out what happens and edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

just use the new keyword so you wont use a reference, or clone object method.

[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How do I do the new bit? That's nto working for me,... Data4JS D4JS = new Data4JS();
   D4JS = (Data4JS)GlobalHelper.GetCurrentSession()["Data4JS"];

Comment: Monkieboy gave a pretty good ideea of how to make a new object, but as i said you can use clone for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

In that case do a deep copy using serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your object is simple enough and has public properties and all you need are the values in the property you could do something similar to this:

```
Data4JS D4JS = (Data4JS)GlobalHelper.GetCurrentSession()["Data4JS"];
Data4JS result = new Data4JS
{
    //Set your result object to the one in 
    //session by manually copying over the property values
    Property1 = D4JS.Property1;
};

GlobalHelper.GetCurrentSession()["Data4JS"] = null; 

return result;
```

Otherwise use what Freeman has suggested as a cleaner way of achieving what you need.